# Get excel cell range to xml format

Tags: c#, xml, excel, dataset, oledbconnection

I want to be able to select my headers of my excel files and a specific row and format that to an xml file. How would I select that range of cells and also get my headers? Here's what I have to select the file and the whole sheet to dataset then xml conversion.

```
public void getXML()
    {
       ...................
        OleDbConnection objConn = new OleDbConnection(connection);
        OleDbCommand objCmd = new OleDbCommand(string.Format(@"Select * From [Sheet1$]"), objConn); 
        ^^^
        //Need to select header plus set of custom cells. like A6: O6

        OleDbDataAdapter objDatAdap = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        objDatAdap.SelectCommand = objCmd;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        objDatAdap.Fill(ds);
        string result;
        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            ds.WriteXml(sw);
            result = sw.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: have you stepped through the code for starters..? secondly if `ds` is being filled you can inspect `ds.Tables[0]` and see what the DataTable looks like from there you can do the following `dsData.WriteXml` look up on MSDN do a google search on how to use the dataset.WriteXML method

Comment: I know what the tables look like, but to convert it to xml, wouldn't i need to multi select the headers as well as any cells I want in that xml file?

Comment: you are loading a dataset from the Select * From[Sheet1$] you should only get column headers one time .. what are you talking about when you ask `wouldn't i need to multi select the headers as well as any cells I want in that xml file?` do a google search on how to convert datatable to xml with particular emphasis on this `Enum` `XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema` also since you will enumerate the data columns do a google search on this as well `MappingType.Attribute` this is actually very simple I've done it many times currently using in a project right now..